# flask_mail I get TWO different FROM lines mail header

Tags: python, email, smtp, flask-mail

I'm using flask_mail configured to use gmail smtp server.  It sends mail fine except all mail looks it is coming from the gmail smtp user name and NOT from what I set in the 'sender' argument of the `mail.send_message(...)` command.  When I look at the source of the generate emails I see 2 different FROM addresses.  How can I change this to show my desired 'from'?

```
    mail.send_message(subject='subject line',
                      sender='my_from_email@gmail.com', 
                      recipients=['my_to_email@gmail.com'],
                      bcc=['bcc_email@gmail.com'],
                      reply_to='my_from_email@gmail.com')
```

snip-it of header looks like...

```
...
From: my_smtp_user_name@gmail.com
X-Google-Original-From: my_from_email@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============8405132704319078372=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
...
```

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: gmail smtp server is preventing email spoofing.

see: https://github.com/gophish/gophish/issues/1311

to fix:

log into your my_smtp_user_name@gmail.com account in Gmail and set up sending email as my_from_email@gmail.com there first. Once your account is allowed and authenticated as allowed to send email as your other account your headers should stop being re-writen.

see : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en